# cannot find Json Object php

Tags: php, json, wordpress

What I want to do is to look for the object name 'imm-sale-value_Huvudbild-fr-kostnadsfrslag' and then delete it.

```js
$JsonOrder_field =
  {
    "imm-sale-value_step_completed_ladda-upp-bilder-till-affrsfrslaget-hr": {
      "label": "",
      "value": "1",
      "summary_placement": null,
      "image_description": null
    },
    "imm-sale-value_Huvudbild-fr-kostnadsfrslag": {
      "label": "Huvudbild f\u00f6r kostnadsf\u00f6rslag",
      "value": "bg.png",
      "summary_placement": "hero",
      "image_description": ""
    },
    "imm-sale-value_Bildruta-1-Kostnadsfrslag": {
      "label": "Bildruta 1 Kostnadsf\u00f6rslag",
      "value": "2_bg.png",
      "summary_placement": "b1",
      "image_description": ""
    },
    "imm-sale-value_Bildruta-3-Kostnadsfrslag": {
      "label": "Bildruta 3 Kostnadsf\u00f6rslag",
      "value": "bg.jpg",
      "summary_placement": "false",
      "image_description": ""
    }
  }

$JsonOrder_field_decode = json_decode($JsonOrder_field, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

I tried to do a foreach loop but that doesnot give me object name it do give only the (`lable, value, summary_placement, image_descriotion`).

Any help or a suggestion of how to search for the required object?

Comment: Shouldn't you put your json data in quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete an element or array from an array by using [PHP UNSET()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)
Here is the code:

```
<?php

$JsonOrder_field ='

    {
      "imm-sale-value_step_completed_ladda-upp-bilder-till-affrsfrslaget-hr": {
        "label": "",
        "value": "1",
        "summary_placement": null,
        "image_description": null
      },
      "imm-sale-value_Huvudbild-fr-kostnadsfrslag": {
        "label": "Huvudbild f\u00f6r kostnadsf\u00f6rslag",
        "value": "bg.png",
        "summary_placement": "hero",
        "image_description": ""
      },
      "imm-sale-value_Bildruta-1-Kostnadsfrslag": {
        "label": "Bildruta 1 Kostnadsf\u00f6rslag",
        "value": "2_bg.png",
        "summary_placement": "b1",
        "image_description": ""
      },
      "imm-sale-value_Bildruta-3-Kostnadsfrslag": {
        "label": "Bildruta 3 Kostnadsf\u00f6rslag",
        "value": "bg.jpg",
        "summary_placement": "false",
        "image_description": ""
      }
    }
';
$JsonOrder_field_decode = json_decode($JsonOrder_field, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
unset($JsonOrder_field_decode['imm-sale-value_Huvudbild-fr-kostnadsfrslag']);
print_r($JsonOrder_field_decode);
  ?>
```